# How do filter inside array and array

Tags: javascript

```json
{
  "view_list": [
    {
      "id": "1"
    },
    {
      "id": "2"
    },
    {
      "id": "3"
    },
    [
      {
        "id": "4"
      },
      {
        "id": "5"
      }
    ],
    {
      "id": "6"
    },
    [
      {
        "id": "7"
      },
      {
        "id": "8"
      }
    ],
    {
      "id": "9"
    },
    {
      "id": "10"
    },
    {
      "id": "11"
    }
  ]
}
```

The above JSON i want filter only id="8" .Actually i try filter method in JavaScript not working.

I filter the array inside array. I used filter method, the method not searched inside array. Give the solution any one.

Comment: It's not clear what you want, please provide an example of the input **and** output that you would want and tell us what you've tried. We can help you fix your code, but we're not a code-producing machine.

Comment: i try search for inside array

Comment: only i filter id="8"  value

Comment: How to delete id without flatmap?

Comment: What do you mean by delete id?

Comment: it's means Remove particular id

Comment: Do you mean remove anything that has id=8?

Comment: yes but without flat

Comment: Without flat, if the value you are seeking is inside an array you need to filter that array too and end result might contain arrays or values. So in this example, you will get a result like this: `[ [  { "id" : "8" } ] ]` Is this ok for you?

Comment: No  "view_list": [
    {
      "id": "1"
    },
    {
      "id": "2"
    },
    {
      "id": "3"
    },
    [
      {
        "id": "4"
      },
      {
        "id": "5"
      }
    ],
    {
      "id": "6"
    },
    [
      {
        "id": "7"
      }
    ],
    {
      "id": "9"
    },
    {
      "id": "10"
    },
    {
      "id": "11"
    }
  ]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.flatMap` method and then filter the array to achieve what you want like below:

```js
const source = {
  "view_list": [{
      "id": "1"
    },
    {
      "id": "2"
    },
    {
      "id": "3"
    },
    [{
        "id": "4"
      },
      {
        "id": "5"
      }
    ],
    {
      "id": "6"
    },
    [{
        "id": "7"
      },
      {
        "id": "8"
      }
    ],
    {
      "id": "9"
    },
    {
      "id": "10"
    },
    {
      "id": "11"
    }
  ]
}

const target = source.view_list.flatMap(r => r).filter(r => r.id === "8")
console.log(target)

const alternate = source.view_list.filter(r =>
  Array.isArray(r) || r.id !== "8" // skip the arrays
).map(r => {
  if (Array.isArray(r)) { // filter the arrays here
    const filtered = r.filter(q=> q.id !== "8")
    return filtered.length ? filtered : null // if it has no elements set it to null
  }
  return r
}).filter(r => r !== null); // filter out null values

console.log(alternate)
```

**Edit**
As the question evolves.

Comment: How to delete id  without flatmap?

Comment: Thanks eldar nice..

Answer (score 1):

you can simply use flat befor find or filter by id

like this :

```
data.view_list.flat().find(view=>view.id == 8)
```

```js
let data = {
  "view_list": [
    {
      "id": "1"
    },
    {
      "id": "2"
    },
    {
      "id": "3"
    },
    [
      {
        "id": "4"
      },
      {
        "id": "5"
      }
    ],
    {
      "id": "6"
    },
    [
      {
        "id": "7"
      },
      {
        "id": "8"
      }
    ],
    {
      "id": "9"
    },
    {
      "id": "10"
    },
    {
      "id": "11"
    }
  ]
}

console.log(data.view_list.flat().find(view=>view.id == 8))
```

Comment: How to delete id without flatmap?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a conbination of flat() and filter(), like this:

```
view_list.flat().filter(d=> d.id ==="8")
```

Answer (score 0):

one way is to flat a.view_list

```
const a = {
  view_list: [
    {
      id: '1'
    },
    {
      id: '2'
    },
    {
      id: '3'
    },
    [
      {
        id: '4'
      },
      {
        id: '5'
      }
    ],
    {
      id: '6'
    },
    [
      {
        id: '7'
      },
      {
        id: '8'
      }
    ],
    {
      id: '9'
    },
    {
      id: '10'
    },
    {
      id: '11'
    }
  ]
}
const list = a.view_list.flat()
a.view_list = list
const item = a.view_list.find(item => item.id === '8')
console.log(item)
```